# ftp connect, processing files from a specific directory

Tags: c++builder

I am very new in c++ and I need to implement an import interface which is going to connect to FTP, read the files from a specific directory and process the files...making some updates in the database and create log file on FTP. I succeeded to connect on FTP and create a directory there, by ftpClient->MKDir("test"), but I don;t know how I can open a directory read the files, opening the files and process the content of the files.

Could someone, please help me?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Far to broad a question. Try to code something up, see where it fail, iterate the code to fix issues. Come back here with specific issues and we can help. We can't write your code for you.

Comment: Yeah, this needs to be narrowed down a lot.

Answer (score 1):

C++Builder ships with Indy, which has a `TIdFTP` client component.  Simply have it `Connect()` to the desired FTP server, `ChangeDir()` to the desired folder if needed, `List()` the current files if needed, `Get()` the desired file(s) to your local machine, process and modify them as needed, and then `Put()` them back into the remote folder.

Comment: Thank you very much! I succeeded to find the number of needed files from a directory, now I will try with List() and than Get() and Put().